Memory leak with threads - labelling the thread memory regions
I am troubleshooting the memory leak with relatively big application.
Initial issue was that threads were not detached, but the process did not perform pthread_join() creating replacement threads, therefore previous threads became zombies until the whole process dies.
However, now, when die/respawn exercise is performed, there's still one region of memory growth (memory leak). Looking at the /proc/PID/maps file all those regions created by the pthread_create() do not have descriptions, and it would greatly help if, after or during creation of the thread, I can label its memory regions with descriptions. Like in the example below with location labelled "heap".
019bd000-01a09000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b6a0e000-b6a10000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b6a10000-b6a31000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
b6a31000-b6a33000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b6a33000-b6a54000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
b6a54000-b6a56000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b6a56000-b6a77000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
b6a77000-b6a79000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b6a79000-b6a9a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0

There's PR_SET_VMA prctrl() operation, but I can't figure out how to use it - it requires address and size - and if it is actually a right call to use.

If not by address and size, how else would you tell the kernel which of those regions you want the name assigned to?

On the other hand, if you're allocating via malloc/free/new/delete etc, rather than using mmap directly, then it's likely that each of those regions mixes together many different allocations, possibly from multiple threads, so I don't see how trying to analyze /proc/PID/maps will help very much.  Normally you want to wrap or trace the higher-level allocation functions instead.  There are lots of tools that can help with this, e.g. valgrind.

@NateEldredge valgrind is not supported on my platform. Section depends on: has all the or-ed options in n state. I tried gdb maintenance info, no useful info. I need to somehow know what each section was created for, or at least at the start time tag it somehow as I have control over the source code and issue is reproducible. I think I need another question for this.

Wouldn't it be simpler to just add logging code to your functions that do allocation and deallocation? You can log the address among any other helpful info, and that would let you correlate it with /proc/pid/maps. Trying to have the kernel keep track of it for you seems overly complicated.

Thanks! I have put diag output into the library under consideration to understand the flow. And seems have found the memory leak bug in the Mosquitto library. The related question I posted here was downvoted (as usual - can't get why this happens as no reason required for this) so I moved to Mosquitto forum.
